# Line break in BlueJ not working (\n \r\n)

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to add a line break in blueJ but it won't work since the return type of String will return the literal character. I have tried both `\r\n` and `\n` same result.

```
public String testNl() {
  String str1 = "1st Line";
  String str2 = "text 2nd";
       
  String linebreak = str1 + "\n" + str2;
       
  return linebreak;
}
```

Result: `1st Line\ntext 2nd`

Comment: This is probably an issue with how BlueJ is printing the output more then what you are doing, as using something like `System.out.println("1st Line\ntext 2nd");` works fine for me (I get two seperate lines - not using BlueJ)

Comment: Would there be any way to make BlueJ accept an empty line character through returning a String?

Comment: What are you doing with the `String`?  Are you using `System.out.println`?

Comment: No, I am using blueJ builtin return screen output to display the text but as you might say there is no other way it seems besides System.out.println

Comment: I'm not familiar with BlueJ, so I have no idea why it's doing what's doing, but it sounds like a issue with BlueJ

Comment: I have tried \r\n still prints out \r\n instead of leaving an empty line. Worth to mention I have tried using it also like this ```1st line\r\n``` same result

Comment: Do you mean you're examining the value with BlueJ's debugger?  If so, I'm not surprised that it shows newlines as `\n`, but that's just so that you can see them easily.  It's not what's actually in the string.

Comment: I am not examining with the debugger, it is the actual output that Bluej gives me.

Comment: If you are looking at the output in the dialog box named "BlueJ: Method Result, containing `String` then a box with `"1st Line\ntext 2nd"`, then that is a debugger, and if you printed that String with `System.out.println(testNl());` you would get two lines.